# Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost

Tags: nginx

I try to access my nginx server on localhost, but my browser gives me this message:

> Unable to connect
>      Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.

I tried to find out the port number used by nginx with this command:

```
netstat -antp
```

but it does not give me any ip or port number for nginx

Comment: Are you sure you installed NGINX and have it running?  `sudo systemctl -l status nginx` will tell us the details we need.  If you had Apache running by the way or something else on Port 80 it will not have started itself up.  Also, make sure you tell us **which version of Ubuntu you are using** so I know which NGINX packages we're working with

Comment: sudo systemctl -l status nginx => running and active  , yes I had apache and I removed from my system , I work in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Show the output of `nginx -T` and sanitize out domain names and IPs but keep everything including ports still in it.  Attach the output as an edit to your question.

Comment: Before I removed apache, localhost it was running apache

Comment: Still need to see your configs, to see if it's listening on another port.  Alternatively, try `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep nginx` and see if anything shows up.

Comment: Actually I am not near to computer , tomorrow I will do that